# Getting error in jenkins of lombok

Tags: jenkins

Following error is generating when jenkins creating a war file

> "[ERROR] Class not found: lombok.NonNul".

Can you please tell me which type of this problem or error?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a typo in the annotation of Lombok: use [NonNull](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html)

Comment: can you please tell me where we use it? I have no good idea about it.

Comment: Do a global search over the coding ;) If it's not used in your coding, maybe it's in one of your dependencies. Use `mvn dependency:tree` in your project and search for "lombok" to find it.

Comment: An example of how lombok is used can be found here: https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html